# how to filter special characters and blank lines in unix

Tags: unix, grep, less-unix, unix-head

I want to display lines containing blank lines and special characters (?#!%#). i used grep command for special characters but its not working for blank line.

```
grep -n '[]?#!*%[]' file
```

if someone can please try this one?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple patterns with `-e` options, so in addition to the present pattern you can give another one for lines containing nothing but blanks:

```
grep -n -e '[]?#!*%[]' -e '^ *$' file
```